# Matrix of $T^{23}$ of an operator of differentiation $P_{45}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be the operator of differentiation in the space $P_{45}(\mathbb{R})$ of polynomials of degree at most 45. Find the matrix of $T^{23}$ in the standard basis which is $\{1,x,...,x^{45}\}$.

Where do I even start with this problem?

Comment: Start by thinking about what it literally means to apply $T^{23}$ to a polynomial. It's a lot of fancy linear algebra stuff but what does it actually mean to "apply the operator $T$ $23$ times to a polynomial"?

Comment: [Avoid no-clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). Please at least show some attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show how to do it on $P_2(R)$ and you can then extend that to $P_{45}(R)$.

---

Let $D\in L(P_2(R))$ be the differentiation operator defined by $$Dp=p'$$

To find the matrix of $D^2$ with respect to the standard basis $\{1, x, x^2\}$, we need to compute $D^2$ for each basis vector. Thus, we have $$D^2(1)=0\\ D^2(x)=0\\ D^2(x^2)=2$$

The columns of $M(D^2)$ consist of the scalars needed to write $D^2(v_j)$ as a linear combination of $\{1, x, x^2\}$. Where $v_j$ denotes one of the basis vectors in $\{1, x, x^2\}$. From the above computations we see that $$D^2(1)=0(1)+0(x)+0(x^2)\\ D^2(x)=0(1)+0(x)+0(x^2)\\ D^2(x^2)=2(1)+0(x)+0(x^2)$$

Thus, the matrix of $D^2$ with respect to the basis $\{1, x, x^2\}$ is $$M(D^2)=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 2\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0& 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

---

You can find a pattern as to what will happen to which basis vector in $\{1, x, \dots,x^{45}\}$ if you were to apply $T^{23}$ to it.

Hope this helps!